# How can I put a HashMap as an input in a Java Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services, hashmap, tibco

I'm getting this error:

The service class "myclass" does not comply to one or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or function correctly.
  The method "mymethod" on the service class "myclass" uses a data type, "java.util.Map", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.

So, I don't know how to use that type of data, as an input I have this:

```
Map<String, String>[] complex
```

I put it as an Array because Tibco (An integration tool) couldn't see the hashmap as various elements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: JAX-RPC supports HashMap. See here http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC2.html . Can you change the input from `Map` to `HashMap`?

Comment: @CoolBeans, not in JAX-RPC 1.1. See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC4.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note, if you are writing a *new* webservice, you should consider using a moderately recent technology.  jax-rpc is *very* outdated and uses soap encodings that are very painful to work with.  consider using jax-ws (built into the jdk these days) or some other webservices implementation which uses document-literal encoding.

Comment: Thanks! I'll consider using jax-ws :D

Answer (score 0):

Map is an interface so you can't use it,but you can use one of the supported implementation classes below:

Refer to this link for supported implementation classes - section entitled JAX-RPC type support

Supported Types: http://sentex.net/~pkomisar/WS/WS_8_JAX-RPC.html

Comment: That is outdated. Check this new support [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC4.html).

Comment: [JAX-RPC 1.1 Specification](http://test.javaranch.com/ulf/jaxrpc-1_1-fr-spec.pdf), section 5.1.3 states: `Other standard Java classes (for example: classes in the Java Collection Framework) are
mapped using pluggable serializers and deserializers. Refer to the chapter 15
(“Extensible Type Mapping”) for more details on the pluggable serializers and
deserializers.` Other link to [spec](http://www.scribd.com/doc/20698/jaxrpc1-1frspec).

Answer (score 0):

Web services are supposed to be interoperable across programming languages and java.util.Map is Java-specific. You should write a facade for that method that converts the contents of the Map into an array.